# Comparing two ArrayLists in UNit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, arraylist

I wrote a Unit Test, where I want to compare two `ArrayLists`.
I am sure these two Lists are equal and the test should pass but he doesn't.

I am comparing them as follow:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
```

`expected` and `actual` are these two `ArrayLists`.

Is it possible to compare two `ArrayLists` as I've written above?

Comment: What *do* the lists contain? Without seeing any data it´s hard to guess why comparing them fails. Anyway there´s also an `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` which will check if the lists contain the same elements not considering their order.

Comment: Maybe they have the same values but they aren't the same instances. That's why your test failes I guess

Comment: @HimBromBeere The Lists are containing String Arrays

Comment: "Is it possible to compare two ArrayLists as I've written above?" Sure, exactly the way you described. However without seeing your lists it´s impossible to see why the comparison fails.

Comment: In your specific case that´s true as you´re just comparing strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()` will be comparing the elements using `Equals()`.

For reference types that do not override `Equals()`, that will do a reference comparison. This is not what you want.

Fortunately, you can work around this because [`CollectionAssert.AreEqual()` has an overload that lets you specify a comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243753.aspx).

Thus, all you need to do is create a comparer which returns zero if two of the elements are equal, and non-zero if they are not. This is slightly complicated by the fact that an `ArrayList` stores objects, so you need to cast to the right type to make the comparison.

> (Note that this is somewhat of an abuse of `IComparer` since it is
>   supposed to return -ve, 0 or +ve to provide an ordered comparison of
>   the left and right hand sides. However, `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()`
>   only uses it to test for equality, so it is enough for us to return
>   zero or non-zero in our implementation.
>
> The `AreEqual()` method would ideally use an
>   [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   to compare the elements, but I think that postdates `AreEqual()` so it
>   wasn't available at the time that `AreEqual()` was written.)

Assuming that your elements are of type `string[]` (which you say they are) then you can create a comparer to compare the elements as follows:

```
var comparer = Comparer<object>.Create((a, b) => ((string[]) a).SequenceEqual((string[]) b) ? 0 : 1);
```

Then you can pass that comparer to `AreEqual()`.

An example will make this clear:

```
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();

list1.Add(Enumerable.Range( 0, 10).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());
list1.Add(Enumerable.Range(10, 10).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());
list1.Add(Enumerable.Range(20, 10).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());

list2.Add(Enumerable.Range( 0, 10).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());
list2.Add(Enumerable.Range(10, 10).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());
list2.Add(Enumerable.Range(20, 10).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());

var comparer = Comparer<object>.Create((a, b) => ((string[]) a).SequenceEqual((string[]) b) ? 0 : 1);
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list1, list2, comparer);
```

This assert will succeed, but to prove that this will detect differences, change the last `list2.Add()` to `list2.Add(Enumerable.Range(20, 9).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());` and the assert will fail.

Comment: If I want to write the comparer in my Program theres an Error by `a).SequenceEqual` that System.Array does not contain a Definition 'SequenceEqual'?

Comment: @PascalHurni `SequenceEqual()` is from Linq - did you put `using System.Linq;` at the start of your program file?

Comment: Ouu heard much about Linq but don't know what it is but this was the problem thank you! The Test Passed now will accept your anwser!